# How to groupby and then weight values according to size of each group

Tags: python, pandas, transform, pandas-groupby

I would like to give each employee a pro rata share after a sale has been made. Therefore I first need to sum up the number of contacts per Customer that leads to a sale and then split the reward the each employee involved in this process.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Cust_ID":[1,1,1,2,3,3], "Employee": ["A","B","B","C","B","A"], "Purchase":[0,0,1,1,0,1]})

df
Cust_ID Employee  Purchase
0        1        A         0
1        1        B         0
2        1        B         1
3        2        C         1
4        3        B         0
5        3        A         1
```

When it takes 3 (or more) steps for the final sale (Cust_ID = 1) the rewards shall be distributed in 50%, 30% and 20% (0%..).
For 2 steps 70% and 30%. One step = 100%

The result should look like this:

```
   Cust_ID Employee  Purchase  Reward
0        1        A         0     0.2
1        1        B         0     0.3
2        1        B         1     0.5
3        2        C         1     1.0
4        3        B         0     0.3
5        3        A         1     0.7
```

I tried using `df["Reward"] = df.groupby("Cust_ID").Purchase.transform("xxx")` but this didn't execute the distributed reward..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's augment the DataFrame:

```
df['Touch'] = df.groupby('Cust_ID').cumcount()
df['Touches'] = df.groupby('Cust_ID').Employee.count()[df.Cust_ID].values
df['Reward'] = 0.0
```

Now we have the basic setup:

```
   Cust_ID Employee  Purchase  Touch  Touches  Reward
0        1        A         0      0        3     0.0
1        1        B         0      1        3     0.0
2        1        B         1      2        3     0.0
3        2        C         1      0        1     0.0
4        3        B         0      0        2     0.0
5        3        A         1      1        2     0.0
```

Finally, apply the reward rules:

```
df.loc[df.Touches == 1, 'Reward'] = 1.0
df.loc[(df.Touches == 2) & (df.Touch == 0), 'Reward'] = 0.3
df.loc[(df.Touches == 2) & (df.Touch == 1), 'Reward'] = 0.7
df.loc[(df.Touches == 3) & (df.Touch == 0), 'Reward'] = 0.2
df.loc[(df.Touches == 3) & (df.Touch == 1), 'Reward'] = 0.3
df.loc[(df.Touches == 3) & (df.Touch == 2), 'Reward'] = 0.5
```

This last part could be done more cleverly using `np.select()`.  This is an exercise for the reader.